# Problem with passing array of strings as argument to thread function of WinAPI

Tags: c++, arrays, string, multithreading, winapi

The task is this: to sort an array of strings using shell sort, sorting should be performed in the thread function using WinAPI. Initially, the program was written using global variables, but it was necessary to pass an array of strings as an argument to the thread function, and then problems began with type casting.

Error on `strcpy_s(strings[i], strings[i + step]);` Error log: `E0304 no instance of overloaded function "strcpy_s" matches the argument list`.

Friends, how to solve this problem? I think the whole problem is how I convert types from void* to an array of strings.

````
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include <string.h>
#include <string> 
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>

using namespace std;

const int row = 10, n = 32;

__int64 to_int64(FILETIME ft)
{
    return static_cast<__int64>(ft.dwHighDateTime) << 32 | ft.dwLowDateTime;
}

DWORD WINAPI shellSort(PVOID pParams) {
    int step = row / 2;
    char** strings = (char**)pParams;
    while (step > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (row - step); i++) {
            while (i >= 0 && strcmp(strings[i], strings[i + step]) > 0)
            {
                char temp[n];
                strcpy_s(temp, strings[i]);
                strcpy_s(strings[i], strings[i + step]);
                strcpy_s(strings[i + step], temp);
                i--;
            }
        }
        step = step / 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    char strings[row][n];

    std::cout << "input " << row << " strings:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        cout << i + 1 << ". ";
        cin.getline(strings[i], n);
    }
    std::cout << "\nOurs strings:\n";
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    printf("\n");

    HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &shellSort, strings, 0, NULL);
    SetThreadPriority(thread, THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL);

    WaitForSingleObject(thread, INFINITE);

    FILETIME ft[4];
    GetThreadTimes(thread, &ft[0], &ft[1], &ft[2], &ft[3]);

    std::cout << (to_int64(ft[1]) - to_int64(ft[0])) << endl;

    printf("Sorted array:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: [CreateThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread): *"A thread in an executable that calls the C run-time library (CRT) should use the `_beginthreadex` and `_endthreadex` functions for thread management rather than `CreateThread` and `ExitThread` \[...\]"*. Concurrency is a tough problem. Diligence is a prerequisite to success.

Comment: Hi AleksMys, if the answer solved your initial issue you can [**accept**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. For new appeared issue feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy_s` takes three arguments. Perhaps you meant to use `strcpy` instead?

```
            strcpy(temp, strings[i]);
            strcpy(strings[i], strings[i + step]);
            strcpy(strings[i + step], temp);
```

There's no issue with converting `void*` here. You just used the wrong number of arguments for the function you were calling.

Comment: @ale Don't change your question to a different one once an answer has been submitted. If you have a new problem, click the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. I rolled back your edits.